# Error processing in payments for facebook canvas app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-canvas

I have created a Unity WebGl game which i want to implement as
Facebook Canvas App.I am using the latest version of Facebook SDK which supports WebGL.I have used:

But everytime i tried to pay it give me:
"There was a problem processing your payment".What could be the reason for this?Please anybody help me?